Add connecting borders to MUI treeview
I was looking to add some borders which connect to the nodes in the mui treeview, but i keep struggling with a single part, that is to not have the vertical border when it is the last leaf node
It is looking something like :
Border example:
whereas it should not have vertical borders around these places:
example for the probelm:
The last leaf node would be like:
leaf border
Here is a codesandbox of the code:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mui-treeview-92r787?file=%2Fsrc%2FTreeview.jsx
Any help would be appreciated!

Replace your "& .${treeItemClasses.groupTransition}" with

"& .MuiCollapse-wrapperInner li": {
marginLeft: 15,
paddingLeft: 18,
borderLeft: 1px dashed ${alpha(theme.palette.text.primary, 0.4)},
borderRadius: 0,
},
"& .MuiCollapse-wrapperInner li:last-child": {
borderLeft: "none",
borderRadius: 0,
background:
"repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0 0.5px,black 0.1px 3px) 0 0% / 0.5px 50% no-repeat",
},
"& .MuiCollapse-wrapperInner li:last-child[aria-expanded=true]": {
background:
"repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0 0.5px,black 0.1px 3px) 0 0% / 0.5px 10% no-repeat",
},

I have modified the solution to accommodate the leaf node example you provided.

This solution does not work, as i mentioned, i was looking to not have the vertical border when it is the last leaf node, this just adds the vertical border in a different way @discovrer

I have modified the solution. Please check if it is what you are looking for.
